# Error when migrating projects in GCP, could someone help me?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, migration

I'm trying to Migrate 2 projects originating "no Organization" to a newly created organization in GCP.

When trying to perform the migration, it displays the error:
Permission denied You do not have the following required permission to perform this action: "resourcemanager.projects.update"

I've tried to perform the procedure via command too but it didn't work either:
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.projects.move) User ["my user"] does not have permission to access projects instance ["my project"] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission.

Group permission that the user participates at the organizational level:
Support Account Administrator
Organization Role Administrator
Organization Policy Administrator
Folder admin
Organization Administrator
Project Creator
Project Mover
Security Center Admin

User permission at the Organization level:
Organization Administrator
Project Mover

User permission at project level:
Owner
Project Mover
Organization Administrator

Does anyone have any more suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Is your issue resolved ? If yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as a solution or can you accept or upvote if the existing answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

As per the given error, it looks like you don’t have the permission to perform the action "resourcemanager.projects.update".  And for that you need to have a “roles/resourcemanager.projectMover” role. Please check [Project move permission](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#permissions_move).

For more details check [Migrating project with no organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#migrating_projects_no_org)

Comment: Having the same problem, despite having the `roles/resourcemanager.projectMover` role on the project. I verified this using `gcloud projects get-iam-policy <project id>`. I've also verified that I have the `roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator` role on the target organization. But I still get the same response as @Leonardo.

Comment: @Brad Have you checked my solution?

Comment: Is your issue resolved ? If yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as a solution or can you accept or upvote if the existing answer helps.

Comment: In my case I also needed "Project Creator" role explicitly set in the target organization. After setting that it worked for me.